# Does $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \arctan\left(\frac {x^2+y^2}{x^4+y^4}\right)$ converge to a finite number?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have tried to solve it and I assume the answer is false (doesn't converge).
**My try :**
Lets take $y=kx$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$ ($x \to 0$).
so $$\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \arctan\left(\frac {x^2+y^2}{x^4+y^4}\right)=\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\arctan\left(\frac {1+k^2}{x^2(1+k^4)}\right)$$
Now each $k$ we pick we get $$\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\arctan(\infty)=\frac {\pi}{2}$$
but that's not enough and I don't see another way to disprove it.
I have tried using the inequality too :
$\arctan(x) \le x$

Comment: When speaking of limits of real functions we generally don't speak about convergence but rather about the existence of limit. We say that the limit does not exist, not that it does not converge. When speaking about sequences, we say that the limit exists, or that the sequence converges.

Answer (score 1):

The limit does not exist, consider the trajectory $\left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 :y=x , x \neq 0, y \neq 0\right\}$

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\arctan\left(\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x^4+y^4}\right)=\lim_{x \to 0}\arctan\left(\dfrac{2x^2}{2x^4}\right)=\lim_{x \to 0}\arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

Now, consider the trajectory $\left\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 :y=\cos(x) , x \neq \pi n -\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \ n \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\arctan\left(\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x^4+y^4}\right)=\lim_{x \to 0}\arctan\left(\dfrac{x^2+\cos^2(x)}{x^4+\cos^4(x)}\right)=\arctan(1)=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$$

Thus, the limit does not exist, because $\dfrac{\pi}{2} \neq \dfrac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: My bad sorry , I edited the question. it supposed to be $y^4$ in the denominator

Comment: How can you make $y$ tends to $0$ with $y=cos(x)$???

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x,y)=\arctan\left(\frac {x^2+y^2}{x^4+y^2}\right).$

We have for $y \ne 0$ that

$$f(0,y)=\arctan (1)= \frac{\pi}{4} \to \frac{\pi}{4}$$

as $y \to 0$. For $x \ne 0$ we get

$$f(x,0)=\arctan (x^{-2}) \to \frac{\pi}{2}$$

as $x \to 0$.

Comment: My bad sorry , I edited the question. it supposed to be $y^4$ in the denominator